# SQL Error 1241: Subquery trouble

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

The problem is that I can't figure out what is the cause of the 1241 error, I'm trying to make a subquery where the prenticies are, and I just finished making one in another code before hand. So it's very similar to one which worked previously, so I'm not too sure what the cause of this error is.

```
select ite.title, ite.unit_price
    from items ite
    where ite.title = 'No Rest For The Weary' AND ite.unit_price =
    (select (ite.unit_price * .1) as '1', (ite.unit_price - '1') as '2'
    from items ite)
```

Edit: The goal is to have the unit_price be increased by 10% in the subquery.
New code with self-join:

```
select ite.title, ite.unit_price
    from items ite
    where ite.title = 'No Rest For The Weary' AND ite.unit_price =
    (select a.unit_price as unit_price1, b.unit_price as unit_price2
    from items a, items b
    where a.unit_price <> b.unit_price);
```

How's this? I think I did it correctly, though I still get the same error despite not adding the 10% part.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Looks like you're trying to filter items by unit price?

Comment: Yes, my goal was to use a subquery to find a new unit_price that was 10% of it's original price.

Comment: Can you instead try a self-join where you specify the 10% in your join condition?

Comment: Sure, I can try, and I mean't to increase the original price by 10%, not to minus it.

Comment: There, added a self-join but it still doesn't work. Would it be due to what I'm using, which is the MySQL Workbench?

Answer (score 0):

Subquery returns two values, and you try to compare it with a column ite.unit_price. So in other words you compare array or list with a scalar.

change the subquery to
(select (ite.unit_price * .1) as '1' from items ite)
 but still the query is quite strange but should not give an error

EDIT:

```
select ite.title, (ite.unit_price * 1.1) AS unit_price 
from items ite 
where   ite.title = 'No Rest For The Weary'
```

if you just want to have a prices with 10%

Comment: It doesn't give the same error, but it gives me the 1242 error where 'subquery returns more then one row', this is fixed with limit 1. This works, but gives no output.
select ite.title, ite.unit_price
 from items ite
    where ite.title = 'No Rest For The Weary' AND ite.unit_price =
    (select (ite.unit_price * .1) as '1' from items ite limit 1);

Comment: change "=" to "IN"  ite.unit_price IN (select (ite.unit_price * .1)

Comment: what exactly do you want to have from whole query? not only from subquery bot from whole quey

Comment: select ite.title, (ite.unit_price * 1.1) AS unit_price
    from items ite
    where ite.title = 'No Rest For The Weary'

Comment: query above if you just want to have a list of items with prices+10%

Comment: Sadly what I'm using doesn't support the "IN" quite yet, and what I'd like the result of this code to be is to have a subquery being used, while specifying "ite.title = 'No Rest For The Weary' ", and to have the unit_price multiplied by 10%. I realized now maybe I can switch these two in the places they are now.

Comment: why you need tht subquery? I dont get it. Just to have it? It looks like it is not needed

Comment: I need the subquery as it's required in a college assignment. I just kept getting hit with the pasky 1241 code. Multiplied by 1.1.. Why didn't I think of that, haha. That query looks totally right when I put it in, but the output won't work. I think I should be able to figure it out from here, thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Think you should be using 'in' and max here:

```
    select ite.title, ite.unit_price
        from items ite
        where ite.title = 'No Rest For The Weary' 
      AND 
  (  ite.unit_price =
        (select max(a.unit_price)  
        from items a, items b
        where a.unit_price <> b.unit_price) 
 or 

ite.unit_price =
        (select max(b.unit_price)  
        from items a, items b
        where a.unit_price <> b.unit_price) )
```

Comment: If you cant use 'in' use 'or'

Comment: Your code definitely looks correct, but the same 1241 error occurs, even when replacing the = / 'in' with 'or'.

Comment: It works but still doesn't return anything. That's super bizarre, unit_price does have numbers in it.. While the title is 'No Rest for the Weary'..

Comment: sounds like u need to adjust your logic - don't really get why you are joining items to itself

Comment: Probably, alright, thanks Daniel. I'll have to do some tinkering with this because your code makes total sense.

Comment: Will do! It tells me it does count, but doesn't display publicly in this post since I'm a new member.